# Tomcat 7: One or more listeners failed to start

Tags: java, tomcat, listener, war

My war file on Tomcat is failing to start. Not sure where to go from here. Below is the output of catalina.log on a restart. I see the javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar error, but I don't think that would prevent the war from starting. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

```
Jun 14, 2017 9:47:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Jun 14, 2017 9:47:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:47:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:47:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:47:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '75' did not find a matching property.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 28 2017 16:01:48 UTC
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.77.0
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.1.12-94.3.4.el6uek.x86_64
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.6.0_41-b41
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Sun Microsystems Inc.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/conf/logging.properties
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/endorsed
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/temp
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2785 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/StudentPlanner-war-4.1.5.war
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/StudentPlanner-war-4.1.5/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/StudentPlanner-war-4.1.5] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/StudentPlanner-war-4.1.5.war has finished in 22,728 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/host-manager
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/host-manager has finished in 388 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/ROOT
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/ROOT has finished in 235 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/docs
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/docs has finished in 156 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/manager
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/manager has finished in 210 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/examples
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/webapps/examples has finished in 1,768 ms
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 14, 2017 9:48:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 25801 ms
```

Comment: take a look at localhost.log

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there are many tomcat as well as jdk versions configured on my system. Issue is resolved when I deleted system level environment variables CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME and set them at user level as per deployment need.